# modprobe amd-rng fails, No such device

Tags: central-processing-unit, modprobe, random-number-generator

When trying to install hw_random to a 2.6 kernel, modprobe returns a FATAL error "No such device" on both CentOS 5.7 and Fedora 15. Both are using the latest kernel, respectively.

The .ko file exists, and config- contains CONFIG_RTC=y and CONFIG_CRYPTO_RNG=m

Both servers are x86_64 AMD processors.

The only google results are very old, often reference the kernel module 'hw_random' (which has been replaced with processor specific modules and don't offer much help.

Has anyone been able to install hw_random? Am I missing a step while installing the module?

*Edit:*

**Fedora 15**

/lib/modules/2.6.40.6-0.fc15.x86_64/kernel/drivers/char/hw_random/amd-rng.ko

`# uname -r`

2.6.40.6-0.fc15.x86_64

`# modprobe -v amd-rng`

insmod /lib/modules/2.6.40.6-0.fc15.x86_64/kernel/drivers/char/hw_random/amd-rng.ko

FATAL: Error inserting amd_rng (/lib/modules/2.6.40.6-0.fc15.x86_64/kernel/drivers/char/hw_random/amd-rng.ko): No such device

**CentOS 5.7**

/lib/modules/2.6.18-274.7.1.el5/kernel/drivers/char/hw_random/amd-rng.ko

`# uname -r`

2.6.18-274.7.1.el5

`# modprobe -v amd-rng`

insmod /lib/modules/2.6.18-274.7.1.el5/kernel/drivers/char/hw_random/amd-rng.ko

FATAL: Error inserting amd_rng (/lib/modules/2.6.18-274.7.1.el5/kernel/drivers/char/hw_random/amd-rng.ko): No such device

Comment: Where is the `.ko` file located? What is the output of `modprobe -v ...`? Also post the `uname -r`?

Comment: @quanta added additional information

Comment: is there any additional info that would be helpful?

Answer (score 4):

"No such device" as in "your computer lacks the required hardware device."

Look at the Linux source code to amd-rng.c for PCI_VDEVICE(AMD, ...) to see the PCI vendor and device numbers.

As an example amd-rng.c may contain:

```
/*
 * Data for PCI driver interface
 *
 * This data only exists for exporting the supported
 * PCI ids via MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE.  We do not actually
 * register a pci_driver, because someone else might one day
 * want to register another driver on the same PCI id.
 */
static const struct pci_device_id pci_tbl[] = {
        { PCI_VDEVICE(AMD, 0x7443), 0, },
        { PCI_VDEVICE(AMD, 0x746b), 0, },
        { 0, }, /* terminate list */
};
```

Those translate into:

```
vendor: 1022 ("Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]"), device: 7443 ("AMD-768 [Opus] ACPI")
vendor: 1022 ("Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]"), device: 746b ("AMD-8111 ACPI")
```

Using `lspci -vnn` will show what PCI devices you do have.  You need to see `1022:7443` or `1022:746b`.